# Facebook API scopes removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, scopes

We are connecting to the FB API to retrieve an access token to be able to publish a post on the user FB page.

We request this permissions:

email, read_insights, pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement, public_profile

When user first connects to their Facebook page the connection is ok and we get all the permissions, all great. However, when the same user tries to connect to a second page the first page access token loses all the permissions and it's left with:

email, read_insights, pages_show_list, public_profile

It seems Facebook remove the first page permissions after the second page permissions are granted.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Explain what _exactly_ you mean by _“tries to connect to a second page”_

Comment: please check access token validity time.
Maybe if you increase the token validity then problem solve